# Arrange multiple plots and keep the x-axis label flush with with axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I am arranging multiple plot using the `patchwork` package. One of the plots has the text arranged vertically, which pushes the x-axis label down (as it should), but when I combine with a second plot, the x-axis labels in both plots are moved down. I would like to keep the x-axis label of the second plot in its original position. Easier to explain with an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

# Toy data
mtcars2 <- mtcars[1:5, ]
mtcars2$mod <- row.names(mtcars2)


# make 2 plots
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars2, aes(mod, mpg)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0, hjust = 1))

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars2, aes(hp, disp)) +
  geom_point()

# arrange plots next to each other
p1 + p2
```

[image]

But I want:

[image]

Is this possible? I'm not tied to `patchwork` and I tried `gridExtra::grid.arrange()` but that resized the plots instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `library(cowplot)`, x axis of `p2` will go down, not like your example, but i wish it help you. If you need to let location of x - axis in same position, please let me know.

## Additional note from @phalteman

By adding `, align = "h", axis = "b"` in `plot_grid`, it really becomes what you wanted!!

```
library(cowplot)
mtcars2 <- mtcars[1:5, ]
mtcars2$mod <- row.names(mtcars2)


# make 2 plots
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars2, aes(mod, mpg)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0, hjust = 1))

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars2, aes(hp, disp)) +
  geom_point()

# arrange plots next to each other

plot_grid(p1, p2, align = "h", axis = "b") #Thanks to @phalteman
```

[image: cowplot]

Comment: Include `align = "h", axis = "b"` in your call to `plot_grid()` and it does exactly what the OP has asked for.